# pass model to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, parameter-passing

here is my view:

```
@model IDictionary<int, RemoteControl.Core.Slot>

<div style="left: 20px; width: 350px">
<form id="rcForm">
@foreach (var a in Model)
{
    <div id="@a.Key-div">
        <div style="float: left; width: 225px">
            <input type="radio" class="slotRadio" name="slots" id="@a.Key" value="@a.Key"/>@a.Value.Name</div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="@a.Value.Status" style="width:20px"/>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="buttonOperation" id="@a.Key-btnON" value="ON" />
            <input disabled="disabled" class="buttonOperation" type="submit" id="@a.Key-btnOFF" value="OFF" /></div>
    </div>
}
</form>
</div>
```

this view receives IDictionary from my Index action of my Home Controller. it displays the elements of the dictionary with each element corresponding a radio button.

each element has a name and status. Every radio button of the elements has two buttons besides it: ON and OFF.

I want to everytime either the ON/OFF button is clicked, the name and status of the element selected in the radio buttons will be passed to an action in a controller. I have been trying to do a form collection but I  always see examples that uses only input text box.. so how could i do this??

PS: dont worry about the readonly and disabled attribs... i am doing something with it in my jquery..

Comment: How will the ON/OFF buttons be clicked when they are disabled?

Comment: add an onclick attribute to each button and handle it client side.